# Even cycles in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm at a dead end with the following question,
It seems simple enough but I cant seem to see it.

Let G be a simple undirected graph with minimal degree 3, show that G contains an even cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: I take it you’re assuming that G is finite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the maximal path $P$ in the graph G. Let it be $u_1u_2...u_k$. By the maximality of the path $P$, we know that all neighbors of $u_1$ belong to {$u_2,u_3,...,u_k$}. Since $3\leq \deg(u_1)$, let $u_i,u_j$ be two neighbors of $u_1$ such that $2<i<j$. Now it is easy to show that one of the following cycles must be even:
$$u_1u_2..u_iu_1$$
$$u_1u_2..u_ju_1$$
$$u_1u_iu_{i+1}..u_{j-1}u_ju_1$$

This is becasue the sum of lengths of all three cycles $=(i)+(j)+(j-i)=2j$ is even, thus it is impossible that the three lengths are odd.

Comment: You can get $\deg$ with `\deg`.

Comment: Why is it not $j+i$? As surly we are going through either the $i$ cycle, the $j$ cycle or both?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1**:

Find a cycle $c$ in $G$ and a path $\pi$ that connects two vertices of $c$ without using an edge of $c$. The path splits $c$ into two cycles $c_1$ and $c_2$. If both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are odd cycles, then the paths $c_1 \setminus \pi$ and $c_2 \setminus \pi$ are either both even or both odd. Hence $c$ is in this case even.

**Hint 2**:
In order to find $c$ and $\pi$ take first all bridges out. Then take any cycle in a component that is not a cycle.

Comment: In the third case, don’t we need to be a bit careful, since the intersection of $c_1$, $c_2$ could contain more edges than just $e$, and indeed may not even be connected?

Comment: I think we need to prove that such a path $\pi$ exists.

Comment: @Peter: The intersection of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is $\pi$.

Comment: @Brian: yes — my comment referred to an earlier version of the answer.